# growth of population- solving initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the initital value problem

$$ P'= \alpha P^{ \beta} , \space \space P(0)=P_0 > 0 $$
with 
$ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{ +} ,\beta \in [1, \infty[ $

and show, that there exists a time T for $ \beta >1$ so that
$$ lim_{ t \rightarrow T} P(t)= \infty $$ and determinine this $T$

The differential equation is seperable, so I can solve

$$ \int_{P_0}^P \frac{1}{ \alpha P(x) } dx = \int_0^t 1 dx $$
$$ \leftrightarrow \frac{x^{1-b}}{a(1-b)} |_{P_0}^P = x |_0^t $$
$$ \leftrightarrow \frac{P^{1-b}}{a(1-b)} - \frac{P_o^{1-b}}{a(1-b)} = t $$

is this right so far? how can I solve it explicit and determine $T$??
thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct so far, besides notation (the power $\beta$ is missing in one equation; one $dx$ should be a $dP$; $a$, $b$ should be $\alpha$, $\beta$). In the particular case $\beta = 1$, we have
$P(t) = P_0 e^{\alpha t}$. For $\beta>1$, the solution of this (power-law) exponential growth model reads
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(t) &= \sqrt[1-\beta]{P_0^{1-\beta} +  \alpha (1-\beta)t} \\
& = \left(P_0^{1/\gamma} +  \tfrac{\alpha}\gamma t\right)^\gamma
\end{aligned}
\qquad\text{where}\qquad \gamma = \tfrac1{1-\beta} < 0 .
$$
The exponential function $x\mapsto x^\gamma$ is singular at the origin. Thus, the above solution becomes infinite at the time $t=T$ which makes the argument of the exponential vanish, i.e. $T = -\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}P_0^{1/\gamma} > 0$.